# Short story with a man inside a time travel box being observed by scientists

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

I read this sometime in the last 3 years or so, but I believe it was older than that, and was included in a collection of time travel stories.

The main thing that I remember from the story is that there is a guy inside of some kind of box or chamber. It is either transparent, or has a window. There are some scientists gathered around who observe him and try to figure out why he is there. He writes messages for them to read, I think, and when viewed from the outside, he appears to be travelling backward in time.

I don't clearly remember how it ends, but I have this vague recollection that one of the scientists eventually enters the box and becomes the backward time travelling passenger. I could be wrong about that part. There was something about reaching a point at which the backward flow of time inside the box and the forward flow of time outside the box would meet up at a point and nobody knew what would happen then.

This story might also be a subplot of a larger novel, but I seem to remember it being a short story.

Comment: Hi there! That's useful info already but could you maybe take a look at [these guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in? Perhaps the most important is - what is "much older"? Would it have been written in the 90s, 50s? ("old" depends a lot on who's asking!)

Comment: Hi, thank you. I removed the "much older" comment, because to be honest, it could be from any time period.

Comment: Probably Ian Watson's "The Very Slow Time Machine".. if so, please confirm, because it would be a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/77221/65768

Comment: That's it! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

Per the OP's comment, this is 1978 short story *The Very Slow Time Machine* by Ian Watson, the first in [the 1979 collection of the same name](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/698910.The_Very_Slow_Time_Machine). The story is about an old man in the first time machine who gets to (the then-future year of) 1985 and realizes that time has started moving backwards.

This is a duplicate now of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/77221/seeking-a-story-about-a-time-traveler-living-backwards-in-a-capsule).